# Using fetch in React with Flask app.route doesn't get the correct information

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, flask

I'm currently trying to create a standard website using a React frontend and Flask/Python backend. I have a separate file, server.py, where I take the data from a NewsAPI and parse it:

```
from flask import Flask
import requests
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/news')
def news():
    response = requests.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?language=en&q=games&apiKey=[API KEY])
    data = response.json()
    authors,titles,descs,urls,urlToImages,publish_dates = [],[],[],[],[],[]
    all_news = {}

    for i in range(0,12):
        authors.append(data['articles'][i]['author'])
        titles.append(data['articles'][i]['title'])
        descs.append(data['articles'][i]['description'])
        urls.append(data['articles'][i]['url'])
        urlToImages.append(data['articles'][i]['urlToImage'])
        publish_dates.append(data['articles'][i]['publishedAt'])
    
    all_news = {"titles": titles, "descriptions":descs, "urls": urls, "urlToImages":urlToImages, "published": publish_dates, "authors": authors}
    return all_news
```

Then, in my App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/news')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data);
    })
  },[]);
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

However, I've been tinkering with this for nearly an entire day now, and I can't seem to get anything other than this error in my console:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU9wv.png)
On further look, the console is instead just fetching the index.html code for the website itself, which would explain why it's not correct JSON format, which I'm assuming is due to some problem with fetching with the route. Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling flask, I've also made sure to have a proxy in my package.json, as the website is on localhost:3000, so I have the proxy there as well, but I've also experimented with other proxies with no avail.

Answer (score 0):

The API endpoint should be the **full path** as `BASE_URL + GIVEN_PATH`, like here it will be-
`fetch('http://localhost:5000/news')` over `fetch('/news')`.

Here, **BASE_URL** as `http://localhost:5000` will be the endpoint where the flask is deployed (5000 is the default port no), and **GIVEN_PATH** as `/news` will be the endpoint where you have to hit.

Thanks!

Comment: this doesn't seem to be working for me, I'm unsure if I'm doing it incorrectly or something?

Comment: From a `react perspective`, I was not able to find any other issue except the above. Maybe some issue could be there inside the flask code. Please wait for others' answers.